# Cannot display image file (base64) already insert to mysql

Tags: php, image, base64, text-editor

Good Evening

I'm sorry about my bad English Language before. I want to ask about how to insert file image base64 into mysql. i currently used text editor which is summernote. In this case if i directly copy and paste the encoded script like this :

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//..
```

into table field that's no problems at all it's look fine and the image file is showing up very well, but if that code inserted throught my form using textarea inside div, the image file is screwed up and it's look like this :

[result display image file from mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEABn.png)

or sometimes it look like this :

[another image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umCu6.png)

I want to showing it up normally. What should i do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the blob field type in MySQL table to save the base64 image. I think you are the using the text field type which changed the few chars in binary data.